# Get current value of a system setting and change value if needed

Tags: java, android

I'm fairly new to Android and Java, but I'm actively learning by watching tutorials and asking questions. As of now, I am practicing by coding my own app in Android Studio. I want to start off with something a little bit tougher. So, let me explain what the app does for you guys. I want the end product to display a UI (obviously) with a button in the middle of the screen that says "Change Value". That's not the hard part for me though. I have the UI set up just to my satisfaction. However, the part that I am struggling with is the Java part. Through my research I couldn't find anything related to what I'm trying to accomplish.

What I want to do is check the value of a string located in the Global Table ("adb_enabled") of the Android Settings Database and if it is enabled ("1") then change it to ("0"). I've seen guides on how to change Brightness and get the current time, but they didn't help me that much.

Here is my code for reference:

```
Settings.Global.putInt( getContentResolver() ,
            Settings.Global.LOCKSCREEN_AD_ENABLED , 0 );
```

Executing the code above I receive the following error: `error: cannot find symbol variable LOCKSCREEN_AD_ENABLED`. Does anyone know how I can fix the above error? Thanks!

Comment: You've used the javascript tag yet your question is Java related.. Are you building an Android native app or a React-Native one?

Comment: I'm building a native app.

Comment: I accidently used the javascript tag instead of Java. I have updated the tag to be correct. I'm sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You can make changes in System Settings **if your App is System App**. Non-system apps i.e. apps installed in data partition can not modify system settings. Non-system apps can open modify Setting only using Intent or System UI.

From official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global):

> Global system settings, containing preferences that always apply
>   identically to all defined users. Applications can read these but are
>   not allowed to write; like the "Secure" settings, these are for
>   preferences that the user must explicitly modify through the system UI
>   or specialized APIs for those values.

If your app is System App then you can use below code to make the changes(**For System App only**):

```
int adb = 0;
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
  adb = Settings.Global.getInt(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),
          Settings.Global.ADB_ENABLED, 0);
}
// toggle the USB debugging setting
adb = adb == 0 ? 1 : 0;
Settings.Secure.putInt(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),
        Settings.Secure.ADB_ENABLED, adb);
```

Add below permissions to `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"></uses-permission>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS"></uses-permission>
```